# How to generate ocamlprof.dump by ocamlcp or ocamloptp

Tags: profiling, ocaml

I read the manual about profiling (`ocamlprof`): http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/profil.html

I have a hard time to use it. The way I tried to do an example with `gprof` is:

For example I have a file name: `ex.ml`

I run: `sudo ocamlopt -p ex.ml -o ex`

then I use: `gprof ex > profile.txt`

It shows me a bunch of information but the column related to time is all `0`

For instance (this taken from my real function):

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
 no time accumulated

  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    
  0.00      0.00     0.00      415     0.00     0.00  caml_page_table_modify
  0.00      0.00     0.00       57     0.00     0.00  caml_get_exception_backtrace
```

I don't understand why at the column time all functions return `0.00`.

In the link above there is a file `ocamlprof.dump`, I don't know how to write a command generate it. How can I generate `ocamlprof.dump`. How can I know the locate of a name for example :`caml_page_table_modify` ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you run the application `ex` between executing the `gprof` command and compilation?

Comment: Just a question, why are you running `ocamlopt` with `sudo`? That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I did not run application ex in between. In my computer I have to use sudo to be able to compile them.